# How to configure an alert rule for backup success in azure

Tags: azure, backup, iaas, azure-backup-vault

I need to get a notification whenever a backup is successfully completed. can anyone provide me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to setup backup alerts in email. Please follow the steps

1. Open your vault and browse to Settings.
2. Click Alerts & Events > Click Backup Alerts. The Backup Alerts dialog opens. This is where all alerts will be displayed. You can filter the information in this blade based on severity, status, time and date.
3. Click Configure Notifications and Enable notifications. Enter the email addresses that you want the alerts to go to. Use a semi-colon ( ; ) to separate multiple addresses.
4. Select what kinds of alerts you want to be notified about, where you can configure to receive backup success alerts.

Click Save. And you are done

Thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is one of the common request Microsoft receives. And this product isn't designed to generate any alert when a backup is successful.

To provide you a solution I need to understand your business requirement. There are few ways to generate alerts, using monitor or backup reports. But these options won't trigger an automated email in case of a successful backup.